I need help to prove that :$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma^{2}(n−\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma^{2}(n+1)}=16$
$$
\mbox{I need help to prove that:}\quad
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma^{2}\left(n − 1/2\right)}{\Gamma^{2}\left(n + 1\right)}=16
$$

The gamma function is a special function that I don't know a lot about.
While I was playing on the Wolfram Alpha website, I found this group that seemed interesting.
I started to solve it.  Now about an hour and a half has passed and nothing new, so I thought of asking a question here. I might find any idea.

Thank you.

$$\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{\Gamma ^2}\left( {n - \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}{{{\Gamma ^2}\left( {n + 1} \right)}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n!}}\frac{{\Gamma \left( {n - \frac{1}{2}} \right)\Gamma \left( {n - \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {n + 1} \right)}}}  = 4\pi \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n!}}\frac{{{{\left( { - \frac{1}{2}} \right)}_n}{{\left( { - \frac{1}{2}} \right)}_n}}}{{{{\left( 1 \right)}_n}}}}   \cr 
  &  = 4\pi {}_2{F_1}\left( { - \frac{1}{2}, - \frac{1}{2};1;1} \right)  \cr 
  & {\text{For}}:\Re \left( c \right) > \Re \left( {a + b} \right){\text{ then }}{}_2{F_1}\left( {a,b;c;1} \right) = \frac{{\Gamma \left( c \right)\Gamma \left( {c - a - b} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {c - a} \right)\Gamma \left( {c - b} \right)}}  \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow {}_2{F_1}\left( { - \frac{1}{2}, - \frac{1}{2};1;1} \right) = \frac{{\Gamma \left( 1 \right)\Gamma \left( 2 \right)}}{{{\Gamma ^2}\left( {\frac{3}{2}} \right)}} = \frac{1}{{\frac{1}{4}{\Gamma ^2}\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)}} = \frac{4}{\pi } \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{\Gamma ^2}\left( {n - \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}{{{\Gamma ^2}\left( {n + 1} \right)}}}  = 4\pi .\frac{4}{\pi } = 16 \cr} $$

More generally:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+a}{a}^2 = 
\frac{1}{4^{1+a}\sqrt{\pi}}\;
\frac{\Gamma(-a-\frac12)}{\Gamma(-a)} .
$$
Take $a=-\frac32$ to recover the OP:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n-\frac32}{-\frac32}^2 = \frac{2\Gamma(1)}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\frac32)} = \frac{4}{\pi} ,
\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n-\frac12)^2}{4\pi\;\Gamma(n+1)^2} = \frac{4}{\pi} .
$$

In fact:
$$
\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{n+a\choose a}{n+b\choose c}=-{\frac {\sin
 \left( \pi\,c \right) \;\Gamma \left( b+1 \right) \Gamma \left( -c-1-a
 \right) }{\pi\,\Gamma \left( b-c-a \right) }}
$$
